# Pinting Data Centric Reports from Silverlight

Tags: printing, silverlight-5.0

I was wondering if Cristal Reports is still part of VS and Silverlight/WPF.

Imagine printing a General Ledger Balance or Profits and Lost Statement, with the Printing API of Silverlight, it would be an ordeal.

It has breaks, totals, balances, etc..

What can I use to make data centric reports from Silverlight/WPF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No Crystal Reports is not part of VS.

For our reporting requirements within Silverlight apps we use SSRS and a third party report viewer control (http://www.perpetuumsoft.com/Silverlight-Viewer-for-Reporting-Services.aspx).  Perpetuum also have a WPF version of the SSRS report viewer.

Comment: Thank you for answering. No good native reporting, that's what I was afraid of.